Local units in a family of $S_4$-extensions
Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and consider the polynomial $f(X)=X^4+aX+1$; we assume that $a$ is chosen such that $f$ is irreducible and that the discriminant $4^4-27a^4=-p$ for some prime $p$ (for example $a=5$ gives $p=16619$). Let $L$ be the splitting field of $f$. We consider the map
\begin{align}
    \mathcal{O}_L^{\times}/\left(\mathcal{O}_L^{\times}\right)^p \to \prod_{\mathfrak{p} | p} \mathcal{O}_{L, \mathfrak{p}}^{\times}/\left(\mathcal{O}_{L, \mathfrak{p}}^{\times}\right)^p,
\end{align}
where the product runs over primes $\mathfrak{p}$ of $\mathcal{O}_L$ dividing $p$.
Question: Is this map injective? When $a=5,21,25$ this is true, as can be checked by explicit computation.
If $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ in $L$, then it is enough to check this for $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ by the Galois equivariance of the map. I am not aware of general techniques for studying this question (other than trying to write down generators of the unit group explicitly, which we haven't been able to do).
Context: The Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to $S_4$ and is unramified outside $p,\infty$. Thus for $p \ge 5$ we get a Galois representation $G_{\mathbb{Q},\{p, \infty\}} \to \operatorname{GL}_3(\mathbb{F}_p)$, and I have a student trying to show it is neat in the sense of Mazur [1]. This would generalize the $S_3$ examples given in [1].
[1] B. Mazur, Deforming Galois representations, Galois groups over Q (Berkeley, CA, 1987),
Math. Sci. Res. Inst. Publ., vol. 16, Springer, New York, 1989, pp. 385–437. MR 1012172

Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

There is not really any hope of answering this question. You can certainly compute the dimensions of each side and guess that the answer is probably yes, but that's about it. Hopefully you at least know that the (much easier) injectivity of the map in characteristic zero from $\mathcal{O}^{\times}_L \otimes \mathbf{Z}_p$ to the local units is a (special case of) a famous open problem in number theory. Also for the desired application you might also want a condition on the $p$-part of the class group as well.

@user491858 Thanks! My student has been able to check that the $p$-part of the class group is trivial in this case.
